# How to get qmake to generate "project dependencies" in a Visual Studio .sln project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a **qmake** build of a few libraries and an app which depends on them.  Using the subdirs template I'm able to get qmake to output a .sln file which works almost to my liking in VC2008.  Though I've specified the dependencies between the targets in every way I've seen described, I end up with no "project dependencies" in the .sln file, and I have to add these in manually.

So far I've tried

```
CONFIG += ordered
```

with correct ordering to no avail.

And similarly the more arcane syntax:

```
client.depends = core common
```

Which also doesn't work.  No dependencies whatsoever show up when I load the sln.

Answer (score 8):

Both `CONFIG += ordered` and `target.depends =` are not supported by the qmake's MSVC backend (solution generator). Back in 2010 with Qt 4.7 around, the docs didn't mention that, but in Qt 4.8 the developers have updated the docs [accordingly](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#target) (see the Target section remarks):

- *.depends* This subproject depends on specified subproject. Available only on **platforms that use makefiles**.
- The *ordered* option is not supported for Visual Studio.

But they had provided a workaround (which is discussed in that [cryptic post](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-07/thread00238-0.html)), and it's still valid and even documented in the same [target](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#target) section. Too bad I had to rebuild qmake and use a debugger to verify that:

> 1. a) There is a Lib/DLL project of which TARGET (the .lib is used and not the .dll) is used on the link line of another project in your solution (you can modify the link line with LIBS).
>
>    b) There is an Exe project of which TARGET is used in a custom build-step of another project in your solution.
> 2. You don't use paths in the TARGET variable (use DESTDIR/DLLDESTDIR for that), e.g, TARGET=$(SOME_VARIABLE)/myLib, won't work.
> 3. If you have a special location for your libs, you specify the -Lmy/library/path and LIBS += mylib, instead of just using LIBS += my/library/path/mylib
> 4. The leaf projects are created before you generate the solution file. (You can use the recursive flag for qmake to do this, like "qmake -tp vc -r [yourproject.pro]"

Basically, qmake will generate dependency when your lib's target name (`yourlib.lib`) is equal to the one of the import libraries of the final app (that has `LIBS += yourlib.lib`).
(See [qmake's source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/qmake/generators/win32/msvc_vcproj.cpp#line566) where the import libraries are added as dependencies, and a [little further](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/qmake/generators/win32/msvc_vcproj.cpp#line631) where they're compared with the project target names)

Here is the minimal setup that generates dependencies in the solution:

```
solution.pro
  TEMPLATE = vcsubdirs
  SUBDIRS = main app

app/app.pro
  LIBS += main.lib

main/main.pro
  TARGET = main
  TEMPLATE = vclib
```

With those, if you run `qmake -r -tp vc`, you'll get the explicit dependency in the generated .sln:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectDependencies) = postSolution
    {E634D0EB-B004-3246-AADA-E383A376158F}.0 = {1BD6E999-63E6-36F5-99EE-1A650332198C}
EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally I know why the heck dependencies aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

From an old mailing list entry:
http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-07/thread00238-0.html

It appears that it tries to figure out which things are dependent for you.  Are you able to build from the sln without entering the project dependencies manually?

Comment: I came across that cryptic post before.  Not sure if the information is current.  I've certainly tried using both the simple and the complex methods it describes, but to no avail.

Without entering the dependencies manually, I can't say that the build really works, no.  It's not completely broken, but there are enough problems, both overt and silent, that it's always worth it to add the deps in by hand.

Comment: Have you tried to set the dependencies with QtCreator and then create the sln?  I don't have my Qt dev machine in front of me, so I can't say for sure what it puts into the pro file when you specify dependencies in the project view.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a wiz in makefiles but if I were you,  I would try to recreate that dependency in with QtCreator by editing the .pro file, running qmake then looking at the auto-generated result in the MAKLEFILE. If you want to know how qmake works then look at the qt documentation.

Comment: I've been over every set of docs I can find.  And done plenty of source diving to boot.  As a side note, the makefiles qmake generates seem to have the dependencies correct.  It's the .sln which has the problem.

Comment: @Michael: do you mean the individual .vcproj files (since I believe that's where those dependencies live).

Comment: I would have guessed this stuff lived in the .sln file, as that's the file which knows about all of the different projects and can connect them with the dependencies I need.