# Unit testing (non-Qt) C++ code in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt-creator, qttest

I have a C++ project that doesn't use Qt. I am using Qt Creator as my IDE because it is very convenient.

I was reading about unit testing in Qt Creator [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html), and I think that Qt Test seems quite good. Is there a way to use Qt Test with my non-Qt C++ project?

Note that I have Qt libraries installed in my PC which I am using to program. But I don't want that the compiled program I release depends on the Qt libraries.

Also, a feature that I liked when I was using Visual Studio is that the tests are run automatically everytime I build my project. Can I do the same with Qt Creator?

By the way, if you can suggest another unit testing framework that I can use easily in Qt Creator, that's also fine.

Comment: Personally I find there is hardly any support for testing in Qt Creator and official documentation for more complex tests with Qt is missing.

Comment: You probably need to set up a Qt project for testing alone, both project sharing common testee files

Comment: @Simon Do you have any other suggestion that I can use with Qt Creator?

Comment: @UmNyobe Can you give a more detail?

Comment: You probably could use Qt Test (or e.g. Boost.Test) as post-build event.

Comment: What project building system are you using? `cmake`, `qmake` (you don't have to use Qt code to use `qmake`) etc. Depending on what system you are using integration with various testing tools might vary greatly. `google test` for example is very easy to use in `cmake`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also unit test (non-Qt) C++ code in Qt Creator with GTest:

https://github.com/google/googletest/

using this great QtCreator plugin:

https://github.com/OneMoreGres/qtc-gtest

I switched from QTest to GTest (for testing Qt applications) for several reasons e.g. haven a nice graphical output and the ability to use a mocking framework (GMock).

Comment: Update: QT Creator now supports adding Google Test projects without the need for the 3rd party plugin. In the New Project wizard, select Other Project > Auto Test Project. The wizard will have a screen that asks which test suite you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Never actually tried to unit test non qt code in QtCreator, but the Qt nature of the code don't matter. That's how I would go :

1. Take your normal, non qt project
2. Add a parent project of type [subdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327075/how-to-get-qmake-to-generate-project-dependencies-in-a-visual-studio-sln-proj) to act like a visual studio solution would.
3. Add another project under the parent, which is a qt test project, ie

   ```
   QT  += testlib
   CONFIG += qtestlib
   ```
4. Find a way to share sources between both. You can either add source files using their relative path, create a static lib, or use a `pri` file ([project header file](https://wiki.qt.io/Including_.pro_Files)) for both non qt and qttestlib projects.

With this configuration, by building the top level project, you will build your normal project and run the test as well.

with `subdir` projects templates you get from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> are not very helpful. But the top level project file can be made as simple as

```
include (commonsrc.pri)

TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered

SUBDIRS += appdir
SUBDIRS += testingdir
```

That's what the top level of one my projects look like.

To avoid headaches match folder hierarchy with subdir hierarchy. For instance

```
solutiondir
     commondir
     appdir
     testingdir
     commonsrc.pri <--- allow you to write commondir\mycpp.cpp in any project
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Boost's unit test framework

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html